# How do i use the saved weights to do prediction next time without any training process?

Tags: python, keras, model, load, predict

I have trained a CNN for pneumonia detection. I have saved the weights of the trained model in the same path. Now I am unable to use the saved model to predict the data after I restarted the program.

I have tried executing the specific lines of code that are responsible for prediction, but then I get import error, from which I can understand that I have to re-run the whole program which again takes time. This is the actual prediction code.

```
res = classifier.predict(test_image)
if res[0][0] == 1:
        prediction = 'pnemonia'
elif res[0][0] == 0:
        prediction = 'normal'
print(prediction)
```

The actual result must be the prediction. Instead, I get

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 5, in <module>
NameError: name 'np' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

np is usually shorthand for Numpy module.  I'm betting that you need to `import numpy as np` in the module where you are getting the error.  Perhaps the import isn't invoked because you are no longer using a different module to generate the weights.